# Use Categories/Tags from one 2sxc app across the site for all apps using the DNN Taxonomy terms list?

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

Looking to use the DNN Taxonomy either by using 2sxc's Folksonomy on its own or if there was a way to join the two tag tables and sync tags across site. For example the 2sxc Blog app has Categories and Tags, the 2sxc News app has Categories but no tags (out of the box), is it possible to use the same Categories list for both apps where the list is actually the tag terms set in the Vocabulary terms db table?

Is this use case something that can be achieved using the visual query designer?

I'm looking to use the 2sxc Blog, 2sxc News apps and create a similar Document management app where all apps use same Categories list (list set by us and will not change) and Tags which admins can add remove similar to Blog app which would be a hierarchical tree list in the Vocabulary terms table.

UPDATE:

Trying to achieve something similar to what WatchersNET has in their TagCloud module (https://github.com/w8tcha/WatchersNET.TagCloud) where you can select a DNN Vocabulary or use a custom tag which is a great feature to incorporate DNN's built in Vocabulary, see below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done, and isn't implemented ATM.

I'm not sure if the DNN Taxonomy would be the ideal place to start - but if you're already using it it could easily work.

Yes, visual query would be a simple place to start - with a Dnn-Sql Data source.

Another alternative is to create a custom WebApi. ATM there is no dropdown-from-webapi yet, but if you need it, I'm sure we could add this in no time :).

Comment: Thanks, so ATM the Categories in the News app can't be synced with the Categories in the Blog app out of the box where you have to manually create two separate Category lists for each app?

How exactly can I use the Dnn-Sql Data source to work with the 'File-List from a Folder' app for example, can I create a new query which only displays files (via a specific view) if url contains the relevant DNN Vocabulary term?

The following were v helpful start:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3n_B_Cv-hdY (intro query designer)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RX-Tj-xCshc (ref tags, url params)

Comment: See UPDATE above